# I2c communication stm32f3 how can i solve?

Tags: stm32, i2c

i want to read touch activity from the touchscreen.If i touch, i want to led blink. Some my definitions in below code but generally i want to get my activity with i2c

Some definitions:

```
    uint8_t deviceaddr;
static uint32_t touch_i2c_read(uint8_t DeviceAddr, uint8_t RegAddr, uint8_t *pBuffer, uint16_t len);
static const int I2C_TIMEOUT = 65536;
unsigned char i2c_buffer[256];
uint32_t res;

This is my i2c read code:

    static uint32_t touch_i2c_read(uint8_t DeviceAddr, uint8_t RegAddr, uint8_t *pBuffer, uint16_t len)
{ //uint8_t deviceaddr ,0x00,(uint8_t *)&buf, sizeof(buf)

  uint32_t timeout = I2C_TIMEOUT;
  while (I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C1, I2C_ISR_BUSY) != RESET)
  {
    if ((timeout--) == 0)
      return 0;
  }
  I2C_TransferHandling(I2C1, DeviceAddr << 1, 1, I2C_SoftEnd_Mode, I2C_Generate_Start_Write);

  /* !!! Wait until TXIS flag is set !!! */
  timeout = I2C_TIMEOUT;
  while (I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C1, I2C_ISR_TXIS) == RESET)
  {
    if ((timeout--) == 0)
      return 0;
  }
}
```

This is my settings

```
void configure_interrupt_pins()
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  EXTI_InitTypeDef EXTI_InitStruct;
  NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStruct;

  GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;
  GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_1;
  GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*ENABLE CLOCK FOR GPIOX*/
  RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
  // ENABLE CLOCK FOR SYSCFG
  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_SYSCFG, ENABLE);
  //SET PIN AS INPUT
  // init_pin(EX_NCVIC_PORT, EX_NCVIC_Pin, GPIO_MODE_INPUT, GPIO_Speed_50MHz, GPIO_OType_PP, GPIO_PuPd_UP);
  //TELL THE SYSTEM THAT YOU WILL USE PXX FOR EXTI_LineX
  SYSCFG_EXTILineConfig(EXTI_PortSourceGPIOx, EXTI_PinSourcex);

  //CONFIGIRATION of exti

  EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_Line = EXTI_Linex;                     //pxx connect to line x
  EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_LineCmd = ENABLE;                      //enable interrupt
  EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_Mode = EXTI_Mode_Interrupt;            //interrupt mode
  EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_Trigger = EXTI_Trigger_Rising_Falling; //triggers on rising and failing edge
  EXTI_Init(&EXTI_InitStruct);                                //add to exti

  //CONFIGURATION of nvic

  NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannel = EXTI0_IRQn;
  NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0x00;
  NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0x00;
  NVIC_InitStruct.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
  NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStruct);
}
```

This is my interrupt

```
  void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
{
  if (EXTI_GetITStatus((EXTI_Line0) != RESET))
  {
    res = touch_i2c_read(0x42, 0x00, i2c_buffer, 22);
    printf("deneme");
    if (!res)
    {
      GPIO_SetBits(GPIOE, GPIO_Pin_13);
    }

    else
    {
      GPIO_SetBits(GPIOE, GPIO_Pin_13);
    }
    EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(EXTI_Line0);
  }
}
```

But my code not working. Stm32 dont understand touch activity how can i solve this.

**Edit i change line 1 every external interupts but i have res value 0 how can i fix this it must be different 0**

Comment: Are you shure that reading the i2c from an interrupt context is correct? As far as I can see, the EXTI0 Interrupt operates at the highest priority. How should I2C return any status if it is blocked by the higher interrupt? In general, you could put some debug messages in your code and investigate more where exactly it fails.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155104/tx-flag-cant-set-how-can-i-fixed yes i did and i found the fails there is my eror

Comment: while (I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2C1, I2C_ISR_TXIS) == RESET)// cant be reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error.
I hadn't any signal pb7 and pb6 so i changed codes as below:

```
    // enable APB1 peripheral clock for I2C1
  RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_I2C1, ENABLE);
  // enable clock for SCL and SDA pins
  RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
```

And then,

Device adress of the FT6236 was mising. it is not include at datasheet so i used debugging. I found the device adress which is the (0x32). And than my code working succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

Using a while() loop in an interrupt will cause problems, because the controller will never exit the loop. Try to use your i2c read Function in main() (with other words, a not-interrupt-context) and look if it works there.